# Different approach to my situation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2003

on a excel sheet I've got columns, each column represents a weeknumber.
I want to calculate the so-called 4 wk average for each row and for each week and this is the formula I use:
**((value*Tvalue)+(value*Tvalue)+(value*Tvalue)+(value*Tvalue))/(Tvalue)** (this is not the actual formula but simplified, that's not really important).

It's the checks that make things a bit more complex. If a value of a weeknr is zero, skip it, but if the next value is also zero, just skip the formula alltogether and make it a zero (or text like "false"). So another thing that has to be accounted for is that if a value is zero, the next weeks value is taken instead.

Example (see included file):
I want to calculate the formula (mov 4wk avg) for the third value for week 12, which will make the formula **(0.2*6)+(0.3*6)** now there's a zero on week 14 so I skip it, then formula will be:
**(0.2*6)+(0.3*6)+(0.6*6)+(0.9*6)/(6)**. Hope that made some sense.

Right now I'm doing this in VBA with a lot of variables and a lot of if statements.
Is there an easier more effective way to go about this?

Example sheet
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3121767/Book1.xlsx

**PS I know the example sheet is a 2007/2010 version but I need to accomplish this for 2003**

Comment: Hi tutu. So only 2 consecutive zeroes are skipped? Now what are you asking of us, if this is possible in general in excel? Also: where is your vba code (It isn't in the excel provided)?

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be `(0.2*6)+(0.2*6)+...`?

Comment: @K_B I will edit my post in a bit with my code, I was just wondering if it could be achieved with an excel formula

Comment: @JüriRuut yes, my bad, I adjusted the file, 0.3 is correct now

Comment: @Remou the excel file is generated from access with all the data. So I am doing excel automation from access

Comment: So, if there are 2 0-values in a block, but they are not sequential, will the final formula be valid?

Comment: @JüriRuut yes when there is just one 0-value, just skip it and take next week. Let's say there is no week left to take the value, then just do the same as 2 0-values.

Comment: @tutu, also reading your chat with Juri Ruut. What the formula does is first multiply all the numbers by TValue and then divide by that same TValue. However in mathematics that makes the TValue totally irrelevant because you multiply and divide all by the same number thus multiply by 1!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array formula could be used (Ctrl-Shift-Enter in formula window, curled brackets will be inserted by Excel itself, not by a user):

A3: T value for row 3
B3:E3: values for single weeks in row 3

```
={IF(OR(SUM(IF((B3:C3)=0;1;0))>1;SUM(IF((C3:D3)=0;1;0))>1;SUM(IF((D3:E3)=0;1;0))>1);"Fail";(B3*$A3+C3*$A3+D3*$A3+E3*$A3)/$A3)}
```

The formula takes pairs of weeks, if the sum of the pair is 0, the whole formula will fail. If there's only one zero, everything will remain the same, as 0*value is equal to skip. 
The formula can be copied to the right and downwards.

The updated exampe is available at http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/4_week_average.xls

Comment: I discovered a flaw: the formula doesn't take into account the need to replace a single 0 with the next week's result. I'd suggest to compile a helper matrix with substituted weeks, if it's possible. If not, some more IF clauses should be nested into the formula.

Comment: Wow it seems this formula does what I want with the exception of what you pointed out. I'm not that good with excel formula's but I'll try putting in some If clauses. Thanks EDIT: it seems the formula also doesn't divide by the Tvalue at the end

Comment: Concerning the TValue: do I understand correctly that only the last pair must be divided with T?

Comment: I edited my post with extra parentheses. So the whole first halve should be divided by the Tvalue actually.

Comment: I'll return to the formula after some hours, when the working day is over.

Comment: Starting at cell B3, the expected result would be (there is one zero spotted in that order, this is skipped)
((0.2*6)+(0.3*6)+(0.6*6)+(0.9*6)) / (6) = 2

Comment: i guess you could simplify it in that way, but the real formula is different and the situation is a bit more complex so that is why I am asking the formula in that particular style so I can adjust it to my needs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19341/discussion-between-juri-ruut-and-tutu)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a 2-step approach

1) transform each cell according to following rules:

```
if myweek = 0 and mynextweek = 0 then
    myweek = 0
elseif myweek = 0 and mynextweek <> 0 then
    myweek = mynextweek
else
    myweek = myweek
endif
```

in Sheet2!B2 I entered  `=IF(AND(Sheet1!B2=0,Sheet1!C2=0),0,IF(Sheet1!B2=0,Sheet1!C2,Sheet1!B2))` and copied to all cells where in Sheet1 dat aexists, together with a copy of the base value in column A

2) Then I create a standard moving average across 4 weeks, for each set of 4 columns, starting with W15 in column M ... matter of taste if you display this in Sheet1 or Sheet2

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this. You use the value of each week multiple times in one formula, if you change it according to step one won't that skew the value for the next iteration?

Comment: sorry no ... there is an implicit ELSE at the end of each line; and the formula below does exactly this ... I edited the algorithm accordingly ... in essence a weekly datum can have 3 values: 0 if itself and the next weeks data is 0, the next weeks datum if it is 0, or its own non-0 datum